# Plotting the parameter space corresponding to a solvable equation

Tags: plotting, parameters

I am considering a function $f(T, c_1, c_2)$ for which I would like to plot the region in the $c_1$ and $c_2$ parameter space that corresponds to the values of $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that $f(T)=0$ has a solution.

I have read about the ParametricRegion but I am not sure this is exactly what I need for this task. Is there a Mathematica function that does this?

Edit: the function $f(T,c_1,c_2)$ is

```
 f[T_,c1_,c2_]:= π rh[T] * (1-rh[T]^2)/(1+3rh[T]^2)*(1+(64 π(c2-c1))) + 64 π^2 c1
```

with

```
 rh[T_] := (1/3)*((4π^2 T^2-3)^(1/2) +2π T)
```

Comment: Please post the expression about the function `f` in Mathematica code.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please post your code in a copy-paste-able form so that potential respondents can experiment with it. You can click "Edit" button under your post and use the `{  }` button in the Edit window to format code. Also, present a minimal example without unnecessary details that replicates your problem. It helps forum contributors to write focused answers.

Comment: @cvgmt, this is now edited.

Comment: `f`  is a function corresponding to `{T,c1,c2}`,so what is the meaning of `f[T]==0`?

Comment: What I meant by this is that f is really only a function of T, but with arbitrary coefficients c1 and c2, and what I was asking about is what values of c1 and c2 make for a f[T] that effectively crosses the x axis at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can look for the c1-c2 region, that satisfies conditons f==0 for any T with analytical solution by Reduce. (I regard T<0 and T<=0 separetly.)

```
rh[T_] = (1/3)*((4 \[Pi]^2 T^2 - 3)^(1/2) + 2 \[Pi] T)

f[T_, c1_, 
  c2_] = \[Pi] rh[
     T]*(1 - rh[T]^2)/(1 + 3 rh[T]^2)*(1 + (64 \[Pi] (c2 - c1))) + 
   64 \[Pi]^2 c1 // Together

red1 = Reduce[Exists[T, T < 0, f[T, c1, c2] == 0], {c1, c1}, Reals] 

red1 // ToRadicals

(*   (c2 < -(1/(64 \[Pi])) && -((-1 - 64 c2 \[Pi])/(352 \[Pi])) + (
     3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[1 + 128 c2 \[Pi] + 4096 c2^2 \[Pi]^2])/(
     1408 \[Pi]) - (1/(1408 \[Pi]))
     3 \[Sqrt](-5 - 640 c2 \[Pi] - 20480 c2^2 \[Pi]^2 - 14/(
         Sqrt[3] Sqrt[1 + 128 c2 \[Pi] + 4096 c2^2 \[Pi]^2]) - (
         896 Sqrt[3] c2 \[Pi])/Sqrt[
         1 + 128 c2 \[Pi] + 4096 c2^2 \[Pi]^2] - (
         57344 Sqrt[3] c2^2 \[Pi]^2)/Sqrt[
         1 + 128 c2 \[Pi] + 4096 c2^2 \[Pi]^2] - (
         3670016 c2^3 \[Pi]^3)/(
         Sqrt[3] Sqrt[1 + 128 c2 \[Pi] + 4096 c2^2 \[Pi]^2])) <= c1 < 
    0) || (c2 == -(1/(64 \[Pi])) && 
   c1 == 0) || (c2 > -(1/(64 \[Pi])) && 
   0 < c1 <= -((-1 - 64 c2 \[Pi])/(352 \[Pi])) + (
     3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[1 + 128 c2 \[Pi] + 4096 c2^2 \[Pi]^2])/(
     1408 \[Pi]) + (1/(1408 \[Pi]))
     3 \[Sqrt](-5 - 640 c2 \[Pi] - 20480 c2^2 \[Pi]^2 - 14/(
         Sqrt[3] Sqrt[1 + 128 c2 \[Pi] + 4096 c2^2 \[Pi]^2]) - (
         896 Sqrt[3] c2 \[Pi])/Sqrt[
         1 + 128 c2 \[Pi] + 4096 c2^2 \[Pi]^2] - (
         57344 Sqrt[3] c2^2 \[Pi]^2)/Sqrt[
         1 + 128 c2 \[Pi] + 4096 c2^2 \[Pi]^2] - (
         3670016 c2^3 \[Pi]^3)/(
         Sqrt[3] Sqrt[1 + 128 c2 \[Pi] + 4096 c2^2 \[Pi]^2])))   *)

red2 = Reduce[Exists[T, T >= 0, f[T, c1, c2] == 0], {c1, c1}, Reals]

(*   (c2 < -(1/(64 \[Pi])) && (1 + 64 c2 \[Pi])/(64 \[Pi]) < 
    c1 <= (-1 - 64 c2 \[Pi])/(1664 \[Pi]) + (
     3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[1 + 128 c2 \[Pi] + 4096 c2^2 \[Pi]^2])/(
     1664 \[Pi])) || (c2 == -(1/(64 \[Pi])) && 
   c1 == 0) || (c2 > -(1/(64 \[Pi])) && (-1 - 64 c2 \[Pi])/(
     1664 \[Pi]) - (
     3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[1 + 128 c2 \[Pi] + 4096 c2^2 \[Pi]^2])/(
     1664 \[Pi]) <= c1 < (1 + 64 c2 \[Pi])/(64 \[Pi]))   *)

{RegionPlot[red1, {c1, -3, 3}, {c2, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  GridLines -> Automatic], 
 RegionPlot[red2, {c1, -3, 3}, {c2, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  GridLines -> Automatic]}
```

[image]

**Remark**

My proposed `ContourPlot3D[f[T, c1, c2] == 0, {c1, -1, 1}, {c2, -1, 1}, {T, 0, 5},   AxesLabel -> {"c1", "c2", "T"}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},   PlotPoints -> 30, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}]`  gives the wanted area regarding 0< T <5 here. But I noticed ContourPlot3d is not exact enough, it misses some pieces.

Answer (score 0):

[`ContourPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot3D.html) may be helpful.

For example,

```
ContourPlot3D[f[z, x, y] == 0, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 2}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"c1", "c2", "T"}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
 MeshStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

Comment: Use `ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity} `  (middle ofc1-c2 area and Infinity for from above) to get a projection to the c1-c2 area for given T - range.  `ContourPlot3D[f[T, c1, c2] == 0, {c1, -1, 1}, {c2, -1, 1}, {T, 0, 5}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"c1", "c2", "T"}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
 PlotPoints -> 30, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}] `  Siple clicking onto the graph gives you back 3 dimensional view.

Comment: ..not clicking, but twisting...

Comment: @Akku14 Thank you both for your suggestions. However, this is not exactly what I was looking for. I'm looking for the region in the {c1,c2} parameter space for which the coefficients c1 and c2 are such that f[T]=0 has a solution somewhere. The value of the T variable has no importance to me, I just want to know for which c1 and c2 f[T] crosses the T axis, and plot this 2D region.

Comment: @gildran ok. The region you seek is the projection onto the xy plane of the ‘contour’ plotted. The Mesh used highlights values of constant T. Perhaps, you can achieve an approximation by using various values of T. Of course, you know context and domain of T and any other constraints on c1 and c2. Good luck :)